# How to execute multiple .subscribe subsequently?

Tags: typescript, promise, angular5

how to stop awaiting at last subscribe and show toaster 'this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Email','

Now accountService.getAll() complites after when changePassword() is complited,
need after sendEmail()

```js
this.busy = this.accountService.getAll().subscribe(
  return this.changePassword().add(() => this.sendEmail());
});

 changePassword() {
   return this.accountService.update(this.account).subscribe(
     response => response,
     e        => this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Change Password', e.error.message))
   ;
}

sendEmail() {
    return this.accountService.sendPasswordEmail(this.account).subscribe(
      (response : any) => this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Email', 'Email has been sent, successfully!'),
      (e)              => this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Email', e.error.message))
    ;
  }
```

Comment: not getting you , can you let me know in which sequence you want to complete code

Comment: @PranayRana, need to await when this.accountService.sendPasswordEmail() is compllited after return true this.accountService.getAll().subscribe

Comment: added answer , can you have try

Comment: is that worked for you or helpful let me know , if there is issue let me know i can try to help

Answer (score 0):

try as below and [check how to handle multiple request here](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2018/06/way-to-handle-parallel-multiple-requests.html)

```
async getAllAccounts() {
 //this will wait till get all account
 this.busy = await this.accountService.getAll().toPromise();
 //this will complete other operation without wait 
 this.changePAssword();
}

changePassword() {

  return this.accountService.update(this.account).pipe(
        tap(() => add(() => this.sendEmail()))
      ).subscribe(
     response => response,
     e  => this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Change Password', e.error.message));
}
```

Comment: Can I set something fake promise like this.busy = await new Promise(); ?

Comment: @aaaaaaaaax10 - you can do it , dummy promise it will work with awai t

Comment: @aaaaaaaaax10 - check this : http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2018/06/way-to-handle-parallel-multiple-requests.html